# Is it possible to convert wordpress language files .mo to .po (and vice versa) in windows?

Tags: language

I know how to convert these files in linux, but I am using Windows 7. Is it possible to use some kind of software and convert these files?

Comment: This is a question about **.MO/.PO translation files**, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Use the tool in http://tools.konstruktors.com/
It works perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.poedit.net/

ps. But ya questions does not belong here

Answer (score 0):

The linux msgunfmt tool is available online [here](http://jarfil.net/convert/msgunfmt.php).

Just simply upload your .mo file(s) using the form.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question don't belong here, but I was having this issue in a WordPress system...

Found the answer [here](http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/how-to-add-and-modify-mo-file), and it's a DOS command `/program files/poedit/bin/msgunfmt ab_AB.mo > ab_AB.po`

Not sure how to do this on OSX... should be easy (`/Applications/Poedit.app/Contents/MacOS/msgunfmt`), but I ended up using Parallels...